# Concurrency::parallel_for (PPL) is creating too many threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, ppl

I'm using `Concurrency::parallel_for()` of Visual Studio 2010's Parallel Patterns Library (PPL) to process an indexed set of tasks (typically, the index set is much larger than the number of threads that can run simultaneously). Each task, before doing a lengthy calculation,  starts by requesting a private working storage resource from a shared resource manager (in case: a view on a task specific memory mapped file, but I think the story-line would be the same if each task requested a private memory allocation from a shared heap).

The usage of the shared resource manager is synchronized with a `Concurrency::critical_section` and here the problem starts: If a first thread/task is in the critical section and a second task makes a request, it has to wait until the first task's request is handled. The PPL apparently then thinks: hey this thread is waiting and there are more tasks to do, hence another thread is created causing up to 870 threads mostly waiting at the same resource manager.

Now as handling the resource request is only a small part of the whole task, I would like to tell the PPL at that part to hold its horses, none of the waits or cooperative blocks should cause new threads to start from an indicated section of a working-thread and my question here is: **if and how I can prevent a specific thread section to create new threads, even if it cooperatively blocks**. I wouldn't mind new threads to be created at other blocks further down the thread's processing path, but no more than say 2* the number of (hyper)cores.

Alternatives that I have considered so far:

1. Queue-up tasks and process the queue from a limited number of threads. Issue: I hoped, PPL's parallel_for would do that by itself.
2. Define a `Concurrency::combinable<Resource> resourceSet`; outside the `Concurrency::parallel_for` and initialize `resourceSet.local()` once to reduce the number of resource requests (by reusing the resources) to the number of threads (which should be less than the number of tasks). Issue: this optimization doesn't prevent the superfluous thread creation.
3. Pre allocate the required resources for each task outside the `parallel_for` loop. Issue: this would request too many system resources whereas limiting the amount of resources to the number of threads/cores would be OK (if that didn't explode).

I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff601930.aspx, section "Do Not Block Repeatedly in a Parallel Loop", but following the advice here would result in no parallel threads at all.

Comment: I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990363/thread-ids-with-ppl-and-parallel-memory-allocation?rq=1 which is very similar to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if it is possible to configure PPL/ConcRT to not use cooperative synchronization or at least to put the limit on the number of threads it creates. I thought it might be controlled via [scheduler policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829269.aspx), but seemingly none of the policy parameters suits for the purpose.

However I have some suggestions you might find useful to mitigate the problem, even if not in the ideal way:

- Instead of `critical_section`, use a non-cooperative synchronization primitive to protect the resource manager. I think (though did not check) that the classical [WinAPI `CRITICAL_SECTION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530.aspx) should succeed. As a radical step in this direction, you may consider other parallel libraries for your code; e.g. [Intel's TBB provides most of PPL API and has more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515097/what-are-the-differences-between-intel-tbb-and-microsoft-ppl/7527541) (disclaimer: I'm affiliated with it).
- Pre-allocate a number of resources outside the parallel loop. One resource per task is not necessary; one per thread should be sufficient. Put these resources into a [`concurrent_queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355358.aspx), and inside a task pop a resource from the queue, use, and then push it back. Also, instead of returning the resource to the queue a thread might hoard it inside a `combinable` object for reuse in other tasks. If the queue happens to be empty (e.g. if PPL oversubscribes the machine), there might be different approaches, e.g. spinning in a loop until some other thread returns a resource, or requesting another resource from the manager. Also you may choose to pre-allocate more resources than the number of threads to minimize chances for resource exhaustion.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider and test non-cooperative sync (although my resource manager is also used in other contexts in which cooperative sync is desired), TBB, and also boost::thread.

Comment: I think popping resources from a queue inside a task would also start new threads when the queue is empty and (cooperatively) blocking and other tasks are still waiting to start.

Comment: `concurrent_queue` has no blocking pop method, only `try_pop()` which immediately returns if the queue is empty (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355358.aspx). So you can e.g. make a spinning loop that calls `try_pop()` until success.

Comment: So if I migrated to TBB, how could I then prevent a specific thread section (a part from the lambda function that I would provide to parallel_for) to create new threads, even if it cooperatively blocks?

Comment: In TBB cooperative synchronization is not used.

Comment: In the case of undersubscription due to a lot of blocking in parallel tasks, we recommend users to initialize TBB with more worker threads.
Also, since synchronization is not cooperative in TBB and the task scheduler does not know of a lock being held, it's not recommended to use a nested parallel construct inside a critical section. So there might be some issues if your resource manager uses parallelism inside.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not "the" solution using PPL, but I think you could do it so easily with a thread pool like [taskqueue](https://github.com/heathkh/taskqueue), you should have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23869221/888576).

So you fill up the queue with your works, it ensures that there will be no more than 'x' tasks working in parallel, where x is `boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()` (yes boost again ...)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have another look at boost::threads although it doesn't seem to have a parallel_for, so I would have to split up a task set into a limited set of task ranges myself.